# Roslyn future branch cannot use C# 7 feature tuples - Error CS0518 Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, c#-7.0

I'm trying to test some C#7 features as outlined in this blog.

https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/lrn-quick-tip-how-to-test-out-c-7-features-with-roslyn/

I've followed the steps many times and I've got the projects to build and open a new instance of Visual Studio. Once I open the instance, I'm then creating a new console project from the file menu. When I attempt to use the Tuples I get the following error.

```
   Error CS0518 Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong? I'm feeling like there's one tweak that's missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382971/predefined-type-system-valuetuple%c2%b42%c2%b4-is-not-defined-or-imported)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue by manually including the `System.ValueTuple` class from the [roslyn github repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/roslyn/future/docs/features/ValueTuples.cs)

Answer (score 8):

Install the "System.ValueTuple" NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio Menu;

`Tools => NuGet Package Manager => Package Manager Console`

Type:

`Install-Package System.ValueTuple`

e.g.:

```
(string Name, int Number) LookupName() // tuple return type
{
    return ("Siya", 16); // tuple literal
}

// In the caller:
var res = LookupName();
var resText = $"Name: {res.Name}, Number: {res.Number}";

Debug.WriteLine(resText);
```