# Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I've installed Visual Studio 15 Preview 3 and tried to use the new tuple feature

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = DoSomething();
    Console.WriteLine(x.x);
}

static (int x, int y) DoSomething()
{
    return (1, 2);
}
```

When I compile I get the error:

> Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported

According to [the blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/13/visual-studio-15-preview-3-for-c-and-visual-basic/), this features should be "on" by default.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does anyone know if the NuGet package is required even in 2017 RTM targeting 4.6.2? It seems like you still need it and I expected that you wouldn't in the final version.

Comment: you can try to use System.Tuple<int, int> instead

Comment: For me this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533630/4383425 was the solution.

Answer (score 572, accepted):

For .NET 4.6.2 or lower, .NET Core 1.x, and .NET Standard 1.x you need to install the NuGet package `System.ValueTuple`:

```powershell
Install-Package "System.ValueTuple"
```

Or using a package reference in VS 2017:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.4.0" />
```

.NET Framework 4.7, .NET Core 2.0, and .NET Standard 2.0 include these types.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean it would work with 4.6.2 ? The Debugger still show's x.Item1 x.Item2. Instead of (x.x and x.y) Do you know if that will change?

Comment: Install-Package "System.ValueTuple" -IncludePrerelease

Comment: Well, it doesn’t seem to be in 4.6.2.

Comment: Works with 4.6.2, still need this package though.

Comment: With .NET 4.7, the package is natively included.

Comment: After installing the package VS still complaining!

Comment: Still need to install this package before using today (13/07/2017). Thanks!

Comment: Just a note (spent some time on this): if you are using package ***Microsoft.Net.Compilers*** in same project, it should be updated to (at least) version 2.0, orelse you will get build/syntax errors. Source/credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41565541/430885.

Comment: Added the package, everything builds, but now unit tests are failing with System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple

Answer (score 47):

It's part of the [`.NET Framework 4.7`](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net47/dotnet47-changes.md#bcl).

As long as you don't target the above framework or higher (or `.NET Core 2.0` / `.NET Standard 2.0`), you'll need to reference `ValueTuple`. Do this by adding the `System.ValueTuple` `NuGet Package`

Comment: I just tried with .net 4.7 and it didn't work? `System.ValueTuple\`2` not found

Comment: I've installed the .net Framework 4.7 and the target pack for Visual Studio. I also selected the version 4.7 in the drop down, but it still doesn't compile.

Comment: Ok I just found the problem: the dll System.ValueTuple was hardcoded in my project file (csproj). Removing this entry from the project file fixed the problem.

Comment: Good solution, but you might add more details. In my case, System.ValueTuple.dll was still hanging out in my bin folder. Once I deleted that, I was good to go. My language version is at `default` and all is working.

Answer (score 14):

The ValueTuple types are built into newer frameworks:

- .NET Framework 4.7
- .NET Core 2.0
- Mono 5.0
- .Net Standard 2.0

Until you target one of those newer framework versions, you need to reference the ValueTuple package.

More details at http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/2017/03/valuetuple-availability.html

Answer (score 5):

For *Visual Studio Code* use the built in *Terminal* and run:

```
dotnet add package "System.ValueTuple"
```

Don't forget to run `dotnet restore` afterwards.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work in VS Code.

Comment: Note: Don't do this with .Net 4.7

Answer (score 4):

I also came accross this issue as I upgraded from .NET 4.6.2 to .NET 4.7.2. Unfortunately, I was not able to remove the package reference to `System.ValueTuple` because another NuGet package I use depends on it.

Finally I was able to locate the root cause: There was a .NET 4.6.2 version of `mscorlib.dll` lying around in the project folder (output of a publish operation) and MSBuild decided to reference this assembly instead of the official .NET 4.7.2 reference assembly located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2`.

Due to the fact that System.ValueTuple was introduced in .NET 4.7, MSBuild failed the compilation because it could not find the type in the reference assembly of .NET 4.6.2.

(duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777123/128709)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have [.NET 4.6.2 Developer Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321) for VS installed and then pull in `System.ValueTuple` package from NuGet.

Comment: Even with .NET 4.6.2 it seems to still need the System.ValueTuple package.

Comment: @mrsundquist, yes anything below 4.7

Answer (score 3):

In case others have the same problem, I ran into this error after updating a project to 4.7. Oddly enough, I had to remove the System.ValueTuple reference for this error to go away.

Answer (score 2):

I would not advise adding `ValueTuple` as a package reference to the .net Framework projects. As you know this assembly is available from 4.7 .NET Framework.

There can be certain situations when your project will try to include at all costs `ValueTuple` from .NET Framework folder instead of package folder and it can cause some assembly not found errors.

We had this problem today in company. We had solution with 2 projects (I oversimplify that) :

- `Lib`
- `Web`

`Lib` was including ValueTuple and `Web` was using `Lib`. It turned out that by some unknown reason `Web` when trying to resolve path to `ValueTuple` was having `HintPath` into .NET Framework directory and was taking incorrect version. Our application was crashing because of that. `ValueTuple` was not defined in `.csproj` of `Web` nor `HintPath` for that assembly. The problem was very weird. Normally it would copy the assembly from package folder. This time was not normal.

For me it is always risk to add `System.*` package references. They are often like time-bomb. They are fine at start and they can explode in your face in the worst moment. My rule of thumb: Do not use `System.*` Nuget package for **.NET Framework** if there is no real need for them.

We resolved our problem by adding manually `ValueTuple` into `.csproj` file inside `Web` project.

Answer (score 0):

I had to check System.ValueTuple.dll file was under source control and correct its reference in .cssproj files:

1. rightclick each project in solution
2. unload project
3. edit .cssproj file: change

< Reference Include="System.ValueTuple" >

< HintPath >

....\ProjectName\ProjectName\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.ValueTuple.dll

< /HintPath >

< /Reference >

into

< Reference Include="System.ValueTuple" >

< HintPath >

..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.4.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll

< /HintPath >

< /Reference >

4. save changes and reload projects
5. find System.ValueTuple.dll and save it into this folder
6. add reference of this file into source control

(Optional): 7. solve same problems with another .dll files this way

Comment: Hard coding a fixed file path (or any string) is never a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

We were seeing this same issue in one of our old projects that was targeting Framework 4.5.2. I tried several scenarios including all of the ones listed above: target 4.6.1, add System.ValueTuple package, delete bin, obj, and .vs folders. No dice. Repeat the same process for 4.7.2. Then tried removing the System.ValueTuple package since I was targeting 4.7.2 as one commenter suggested. Still nothing. Checked csproj file reference path. Looks right. Even dropped back down to 4.5.2 and installing the package again. All this with several VS restarts and deleting the same folders several times. Literally nothing worked.

I had to refactor to use a struct instead. I hope others don't continue to run into this issue in the future but thought this might be helpful if you end up as stumped up as we were.