# LINQ to SQL -> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Let say I have 2 tables which is Student and School. Within my Student table I have a fkSchoolId linking to a School record. However, if I retrieve my record as below

```
public static List<Student> GetByType(string connString, int type)
{
    using (mydb_DataContext db = new mydb_dbDataContext(connString))
    {
        return (from t1 in db.Students
                where t1.type = type
                select t1).ToList();
    }
}
```

I will have the list of Student objects where I can access it in a foreach loop. But when I do as below, I will get an error when retrieving the school name.

```
foreach(Student student in DAL.StudentLogic.GetByType(5))
{
    string schoolName = student.School.Name;
}
```

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.'

May I know how can I get the foreign information stored in the return object so that I can access them? Or better way, if I can specify to load up just the school Name?

Updated:
If I do as follow, it works, but not sure how much it will impact the performance. I will do a benchmark and update to this topic again next week.

```
public static List<Student> GetByType(string connString, int type)
{
    using (mydb_DataContext db = new mydb_dbDataContext(connString))
    {
        List<Student> students = (from t1 in db.Students where t1.type = type select t1).ToList();

        foreach(Student student in students)
        {
            student.School.Name = db.Schools.Where(q => q.SchoolId == student.fkSchoolId).FirstOrDefault().Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I'll be able to access to student.School.Name in my return object.

Comment: This solution will perform a separate query for each returned student. Shame to go to DB so many time..

Comment: @GiladGreen I agreed.. Not the best performance.. I wonder why LINQ to SQL does not have a simple way to stat which I would like to bring back.. I tried DeferredLoadingEnabled but I'm still getting null foreign object. I do not wish to step into C#7. If I use Entity Framework, there is a .Include there, will it work with EF to solve my problem?

Comment: But include is not available in LINQ to SQL right?

Answer (score 5):

Set the [`DeferredLoadingEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.deferredloadingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false`:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to delay-load one-to-many or one-to-one relationships.

Therefor the related data will be retrieved when materializing the query and not retrieved in a later stage (after context was disposed)

```
public static List<Student> GetByType(string connString, int type)
{
    using (mydb_DataContext db = new mydb_dbDataContext(connString))
    {
        db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
        return (from t1 in db.Students
                where t1.type = type
                select t1).ToList();
    }
}
```

However consider thinking (depends on overall design/ program requirements and load) of having the context kept open for the lifetime of the class this functions sits in (in seems like a DAL class). Then implement the `IDisposable` interface and dispose the context in it. (Remember that the `Dispose` must be called explicitly).

---

If all you want is the school name and you are using C# 7.0 you can use the [named tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) this way:

```
public static List<(Student Student, string SchoolName)> GetByType(string connString, int type)
{
    using (mydb_DataContext db = new mydb_dbDataContext(connString))
    {
        return (from t1 in db.Students
                join school in db.Schoold on t1.SchoolId equals school.Id
                where t1.type = type
                select (t1, school.Name)).ToList();
    }
}
```

*If you get [compilation error CS8137](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40826704/6400526) then you need to install the Nuget package of `System.ValueTuple`*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it. I have just updated my question on another method that I'm trying. I will test the performance and update back to this thread.

Comment: @teapeng - missed the linq to sql and not EF. Sorry. Have a look [here for setting the relationships](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37784/One-Many-and-One-One-relationship-using-LINQ-to-SQ) and otherwise you can perform a join to get the data

Comment: @teapeng - updated with what the join might look like

Answer (score 2):

With Linq2Sql you can use [LoadWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548760%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), eg

```
using (mydb_DataContext db = new mydb_dbDataContext(connString))
{
    DataLoadOptions op = new DataLoadOptions();
    op.LoadWith<Student>(o => o.School);

    db.LoadOptions = op;
    return (from t1 in db.Students
        where t1.type = type
        select t1).ToList();
}
```

The one downside is that this is retrieving all columns in the school table.