# Is there a more efficient way than using dictionary as parameter

Tags: c#

Is there a more efficient way of doing this.

the function:

```
public void someFunction(Dictionary<string, object> args){
   foreach (var item in args){
       Console.WriteLine("key: " + item.Key + " value: " + item.Value);
   }
}
```

Calling the function what doesn't look nice: **<-- here is the problem**

```
someFunction(new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "number", 3 },
            { "text", "Some Text" }
}));
```

Output:

```
key: number value: 3
key: text value: Some Text
```

I want to achieve something like this **where I can always change the passing variable names and values**

```
someFunction(["number" => 3, "text" => "Some Text"]);
```

I want to pass a string name and an object type array to the function so I can iterate through it. This code works but I want it to look neater.

In PHP there is http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Which makes it able to have the name of the variable and the value in an array usable in your code. With c# I have to use a whole dictionary.

I would like to see a more efficient way.

Edit:
THANK YOU ALL. Didn't know I would get answers so fast 0_0

Comment: you can use a MultiValue Dictionary.. for example `Dictionary<Key, List<Values>>` or a Class, and in your case you will only iterate a `List<object>`

Comment: I don't think you can iterate a dictionary directly, but you can iterate it's Keys collection. Are you having performance problems with the dictionary?

Comment: you couse use a class...

Comment: If you just need something to itrate through you should not use a dictionary to combine a string with some object. This could be done with a list of a struct where inserting is not that slow.

Comment: My problem is with calling the function. It takes more lines which doesn't look nice where as in php I can do everything in one line.

Comment: @MoDGenesis don't forget to mark the answer that helped you the most

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for sparse syntax for the caller, you can use an anonymous type, similar to the way that jquery passes optional options around. Example:

```
public static void someFunction(object input)
{
    foreach (var p in input.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
             Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(input));
}
```

The function itself is a little more messy, but for the caller, the syntax is pretty lightweight:

```
someFunction( new { Number = 3, Text = "Some text"});
```

output:

```
Number=3
Text=Some text
```

If you plan to do this a lot, you can make it a little less painful with an extension method. I named mine `Extract()`, below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> Extract<T>(this T input) where T : class
    {
        return input
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .ToDictionary( p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(input));
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void someFunction(object input)
    {
        var parameters = input.Extract();  //Magic

        Console.WriteLine("There were {0} parameters, as follows:", parameters.Count);
        foreach (var p in parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", p.Key, p.Value);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        someFunction(new { number = 3, text = "SomeText" } );
        someFunction(new { another = 3.14F, example = new DateTime(2017, 12, 15) } );
    }
}
```

Output on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xbc71T):

```
There were 2 parameters, as follows:
number=3
text=SomeText
There were 2 parameters, as follows:
another=3.14
example=12/15/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

The main downside with this approach is that you can't use interfaces or do anything to require that certain keys be present. Also, you have to use Reflection, which is a little bit more work. If you'd like to avoid these downsides, you could use the same approach but with a non-anonymous type, like this:

```
class SomeFunctionParams
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public static void someFunction(SomeFunctionParams params)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number={0}", params.Number);
    Console.WriteLine("Text={0}", params.Text);
}
```

...but then you'd lose the dynamic advantages of the anonymous type.

Another option is expose every possible key as an optional parameter, and only provide the ones you want:

```
void someFunction(int Number = default(int), string Text = default(string), DateTime SomeOtherParam = default(DateTime))
{
    if (Number != default(int)) Console.WriteLine("Number={0}", Number);
    if (Text != default(string)) Console.WriteLine("Text={0}", Text);
    if (SomeOtherParam != default(DateTime)) Console.WriteLine("SomeOtherParam={0}", SomeOtherParam);
}

someFunction(Number : 3, Text : "Some text");
```

Comment: Personally, I like it, as it also assures that you are not sending the same keys, and it looks the most like the implementation the OP wanted. However, I would personally like to see a bit more information about the downsides this method has

Comment: Could you also say how to select count() from the object type? Also with the second option, you lose the ability to change the variable names.

Comment: This work around is legendary. Seems like that if I wanted to come up with it I needed more knowledge in c# then I have now. (reflection etc.) hence, why I asked how to do count()

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use the [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword for allowing a dynamic number of arguments

You could then for example do (it doesn't have to be a [`KeyValuePair<string, object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx), it could be a [`Tuple<string, object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
public void AddSomeKeys(params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] arguments) {
    foreach (var item in arguments){
        Console.WriteLine($"key: {item.Key} value: {item.Value}");
    }
}
```

In C# 7 you could make it even a bit easier, by making use of the [ValueTuple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/)

```
public void AddSomeKeys(params (string key, object value)[] arguments) {
    foreach (var item in arguments){
        Console.WriteLine($"key: {item.key} value: {item.value}");
    }
}
```

Or you could use the more anonymous ValueTuple

```
public void AddSomeKeys(params (string, object)[] arguments) {
    foreach (var item in arguments){
        Console.WriteLine($"key: {item.Item1} value: {item.Item2}");
    }
}
```

In both cases, you could call the methods like:

```
AddSomeKeys(new KeyValuePair<string, object>( "item1", "value1" ), new KeyValuePair<string, object>( "item2", "value2" ) );
```

Or with the second version

```
AddSomeKeys( ( key: "item1", value: "value1" ), ( key: "item2", value: "value2" ) );
```

Or with the third version

```
AddSomeKeys( ( "item1", "value1" ), ( "item2", "value2" ) );
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled I did mention that :)

Comment: Correct, didn't see that, sorry.

Comment: There is a package which makes it available to use ValueTuple https://stackoverflow.com/a/40826779/5517161

Comment: This function is nice but I can't pass integers, only strings. Change the second string with object for other readers.

Comment: @MoDGenesis Yup, I updated it to use string, object instead (and added string interpolation instead of concatination)

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm using your example :)

Comment: @MoDGenesis Thanks, in my comment on your post I mainly ment that you should check to accept an answer, which is described [in the helpsection](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

[C# 6 added a new syntax](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2015/04/C-Sharp-Dictionary-Initializers.aspx?m=1) that makes inline initialization slightly easier to read:

```
someFunction(new Dictionary<string, object> {
    ["number"]=3, ["text"]="Some Text"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Iterate(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["1"] = "one", ["2"] = "Two" });
    Console.Read();
}

public static void Iterate(Dictionary<string, object> args)
{
    foreach (var item in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("key: " + item.Key + " value: " + item.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) in the begining of the file:

```
using D = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;
```

or

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Namespace {
    using D = Dictionary<string, object>;
```

and then use `D` instead of `Dictionary<string, object>` :

```
public void someMethod(D args){
   foreach (var item in args){
       Console.WriteLine("key: " + item.Key + " value: " + item.Value);
   }
}
```

and

```
someMethod(new D { { "number", 3 }, { "text", "Some Text" } }));
```

---

If all of the arguments are known, it's much more efficient to use [optional arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) :

```
void someMethod(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0, int d = 0, int e = 0){
    Console.WriteLine($"key: {nameof(a)} value: {a}");
    Console.WriteLine($"key: {nameof(b)} value: {b}");
    // ...
}
```

and sample use:

```
someMethod(d: 1, b: 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a handler class that takes anonymous types and lets you easily get the values you need. Might be handy for someone working with dynamic data.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3YZSwL

Program

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var parameters = new { number = 42, text = "Hello World", isValid = true };
        
        DynamicParameterHandler handler = new DynamicParameterHandler(parameters);
        handler.AddParameter("added", "I am added");

        int number = handler.GetValue<int>("number");
        string text = handler.GetValue<string>("text");
        bool? isValid = handler.GetValueOrDefault<bool?>("isValid");
        int defaultValue = handler.GetValueOrDefault<int>("nonExistingProperty");
        string added = handler.GetValueOrDefault<string>("added");

        Console.WriteLine($"Number: {number}, Text: {text}, IsValid: {isValid}, DefaultValue: {defaultValue}, Added: {added}");
    }
}
```

DynamicParameterHandler

```
public class DynamicParameterHandler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public DynamicParameterHandler(object parameters)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            _properties[property.Name] = property.GetValue(parameters);
        }
    }

    public void AddParameter(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        _properties[propertyName] = value;
    }

    public bool DeleteParameter(string propertyName)
    {
        return _properties.Remove(propertyName);
    }

    public T GetValue<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        if (_properties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            return (T)_properties[propertyName];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{propertyName}' not found.");
        }
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        return _properties.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var property) ? (T)property : default;
    }

    public Type GetPropertyType(string propertyName)
    {
        if (_properties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            return _properties[propertyName]?.GetType();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{propertyName}' not found.");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var property in _properties)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"Key: {property.Key}, Value: {property.Value}, Type: {property.Value?.GetType()}");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```