# Deconstruction in foreach over Dictionary

Tags: c#-7.0

Is it possible in C#7 to use deconstruction in a foreach-loop over a Dictionary? Something like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>{ ["Bob"] = 32, ["Alice"] = 17 };
foreach (var (name, age) in dic)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} is {age} years old.");
}
```

It doesn't seem to work with Visual Studio 2017 RC4 and .NET Framework 4.6.2:

> error CS1061: 'KeyValuePair' does not contain a definition for 'Deconstruct' and no extension method 'Deconstruct' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyValuePair' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This is still a problem in VS Code 1.61.0 with C# extension 1.23.16.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

First you have to add an extension method for `KeyValuePair`:

```
public static void Deconstruct<T1, T2>(this KeyValuePair<T1, T2> tuple, out T1 key, out T2 value)
{
    key = tuple.Key;
    value = tuple.Value;
}
```

Then you will get a different error:

> error CS8179: Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38383064/2102827) you have to install the NuGet package `System.ValueTuple`.

Then it should compile. However Visual Studio 2017 RC4 will say that it cannot resolve the symbol names `name` and `age`. They should hopefully fix this in a future update.

Comment: Not sure why RC4 is giving you that error. `name` and `age` resolve just fine and the code works when I try it.

Comment: So `static void Deconstruct<T1, T2>(this KeyValuePair<T1, T2>` is going to be an extension method I'll have to write over and over in each project once VS2017 drops?  Wonderful.

Comment: @Tinister: Maybe they'll have it implemented for the release next week.

Comment: @Tinister, why rewrite it every time? Create a nuget package and import it into your projects...

Comment: @Tinister you should already be pushing your own reusable code into your own library

Answer (score 93):

If you don't like having to write the `Deconstruct` method, especially if you only need it in one place, here's how to do it as a one-liner with LINQ:

Using your original dictionary:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>{ ["Bob"] = 32, ["Alice"] = 17 };
```

You can do it like this:

```
foreach (var (name, age) in dic.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} is {age} years old.");
}
```

Comment: this will also work when joining via LINQ, when you end up by having an anon class with one field for each model in the result;

Answer (score 51):

`Deconstruct` of `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is [implemented in .NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.deconstruct?view=netcore-2.0), but not in .NET Framework (up to 4.8 preview) unfortunately.

Comment: Deconstruct on KeyValuePair will be included into .NET Standard 2.1

Comment: That's why some of my projects that target multiple frameworks (including .net-core-2.0) sometimes support it and another time not. I thought I'm loosing my mind.

Comment: It works in .NET 5.