# how to return two integer values in c#

Tags: c#

I tried like below

```
public int[] GetCompletedCalls()
        {
           int[] minMax = int[2];
           minMax[0] = countCompleted;
           minMax[1] = countPendings;
           return minMax;
        }
```

> But at declaring an array variable throwing an error: Invalid
>   expression term 'int'

Comment: you forgot the `new` keyword --> `new int[2];`

Comment: `int[] minMax = int[2];` should be `int[] minMax = new int[2];`

Comment: You may also want to read up on [Tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples)

Comment: Yeah, [tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42926301/1997232) was the first thought after reading the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use the `new` keyword:

```
int[] minMax = new int[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. The easiest one needs only a single correction:

```
int[] minMax = int[2];
```

should be

```
int[] minMax = new int[2];
```

Another opportunity is to do this:

```
return new [] { countCompleted, countPendings};
```

or also this:

```
public void GetCompletedCalls(out int completed, out int pending)
{
    completed = countCompleted;
    pending = countPendings;
}
```

or also this which uses a Tuple instead (requires C#7):

```
public (int, int) GetCompletedCalls()
{
    return (countCompleted, countPendings);
}
```

Comment: More return multiple values options: custom type (class or struct) and old [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netframework-4.7.2).