# Cant connect to my local mysql server from c# console application

Tags: c#, mysql, console, connection

I am trying to connect to my local mysql server from my console, but whenever I try to open a connection it gives me a file not found exception. The connection string should be correct.

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder cstring = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
cstring.UserID = "root";
cstring.Password = "MyPassword";
cstring.Database = "MyDatabase";
cstring.Server = "localhost";
cstring.Port = 3306;



MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(cstring.GetConnectionString(true));
connect.Open(); //Here I get a file not found exception
```

Exact error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

EDIT: The server has .NET Connector installed

Comment: Where is your connection string?  cstring.ToString() is not a string it is a class object.

Comment: Fixed it but it still doesn´t work

Comment: [May be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844798/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-valuetuple-version-0-0-0-0-or-one-of-i)

Comment: What does the connection string look like?  You still are getting a bad connection string.

Comment: "user id=root;password=MyPassword;database=MyDatabase;server=localhost;port=3306"