# How can I make <configSections> <runtime> inside <configuration> work together

Tags: c#, nuget, app-config

This is the app.config in my WPF application:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <section name="XXX.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <section name="XXX.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>

      <userSettings>...</userSettings>
      <applicationSettings>...</applicationSettings>

      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
      </startup>

      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Run application get exception:

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one  element
>   allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the
>   root  element

**If I remove `<runtime>` section application works well** but will cause a bulid time warning:

[image]

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533630/3907561

So my question is **How can I make "configSections" "runtime" inside "configuration" work together** ?

Comment: That's confusing. What that error means is "there must be only one  configSections section and it must be the first child of the configuration element" but that seems to be the case in your config. Is there another `configSections` declaration in the `<userSettings>` or   `<applicationSettings>`?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it is because you have declared multiple sectionGroups?

Comment: If I remove <runtime> section, all works well except the build time warning. @stuartd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clean and rebuild the Solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with using **`<runtime>`** and **`<configSections>`** together( I did 2 projects with it, and both are OK).

I don't know what are you configuring with bellow sections, maybe your problem is inside them:

```
      <userSettings>...</userSettings>
      <applicationSettings>...</applicationSettings>
```

Comment: Damn, after I clean and rebuild, all works well. Anyway, thanks your tips.