# "Predefined type System.ValueTuple is not defined or imported" after upgrading to .NET 4.7

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm upgrading an existing solution from .NET 4.6.2 to .NET 4.7. This solution depends on several nuget packages that target .NET 4.6.2 and hence depend on the nuget [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) package.

But after upgrading, I'm getting a whole bunch of these build errors:

`` Error CS8179 Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported ``

I can't remove the `System.ValueTuple` package, as suggested in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43264775/68231), because other packages depend on it. (And if I force it, they seem to blow up.)

Any suggestions?

**Update 8/8/17**

I've figured out that I *can* remove the `System.ValueTuple` package, and I can get the solution to compile that way. However, I've got a dozen NuGet packages in the solution which appear to be targeting .NET 4.6.2, and hence require `System.ValueTuple` as a dependency. I can install those, and then force remove the `System.ValueTuple` package, but if any of those packages have an update, and I install the update - then the `System.ValueTuple` package gets installed again, and the system stops building until I remove the package all over again.

In other words, I can make it all work - but it seems awkward and kludgy. Surely there's a better way to approach this?

Comment: What version of the package are you using? I would expect this to be fixed if you update to the pre-release version (4.4) of the ValueTuple package.

Comment: Shipping VS2017 and C# v7 before 4.7 was done was nothing short from a massive big blunder.  This stuff just isn't done yet and targeting 4.7 is too soon.  You'd give me a pretty big headache, I can't get 4.7 installed on my machine and can't get a decent diagnostic.  Dealing with Microsoft updates is getting to be a pretty doggone big pita lately.  Just wait.

Comment: Sorry for the hiccup. We just pushed an updated (stable) System.ValueTuple package that fully supports .NET Framework 4.7. Please give that a try.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/25 for more details.

Comment: Related post - [Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38382971/465053)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, upgrade to [System.ValueTuple 4.4.0](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/25).

Here is why:

> The NuGet package `System.ValueTuple` provides the `ValueTuple` types which are required for the C# tuple syntax. In .NET Framework 4.7 we've added the types directly to `mscorlib`. If you use both, the NuGet package, as well as .NET Framework 4.7 you'll end up seeing the same types multiple times. This results in issues like this one reported on Stack Overflow.
>
> We've updated the NuGet package to type forward the tuple types on .NET Framework 4.7 to `mscorlib`. This unifies the types and thus allows you to consume other libraries and NuGet packages that depend on `System.ValueTuple` while still targeting .NET Framework 4.7.

See [release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/25).

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studion ,NuGet package System.ValueTuple provides the ValueTuple types. So Update System.ValueTuple to latest version v4.4.0. Means Upgrade the System.ValueTuple to higher version then the current or previous one.