# C# constructor error when using the imported DLL vs Original project

Tags: c#, tuples, dllimport

So, when a new class is written in the same C# project that inherits one of the classes from that project, everything goes well, but, when I create a new C# project and I add a reference to the original project dll, and then try to use a constructor which calls the base constructor from one of the classes in the original project, I get the error shown in the  picture.

[image]

Inheriting the class and using other class attributes goes without problems, but there seems to be a problem with Tuple.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but are you sure that your new project is targeting the same C# version as the original project? By the same token, if the new project is targeting a version of .Net less than 4, then you would have issues, because Tuples didn't exist before .Net 4.0.

Comment: Both projects target the newest version of .Net (4.6.2).

Comment: And they are compiling against the same version of C#?

Comment: 4.7.1 is the current newest version of .NET.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339914/predefined-type-system-valuetuple-is-not-defined-or-imported-after-upgrading-t/45598683

Comment: Ok, installing the latest version of System.ValueType (4.4) solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterAbolins: That question is about using .NET 4.7 and using the right reference for value tuples there. This question is about using .NET 4.6.2. I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding a reference to the original project DLL doesn't add references to all that project's references.

Look at the original project's references - one of them will be to `System.ValueTuple` NuGet package. Add that reference to your second project, and everything should be fine.

Note that if you use NuGet package references (and project references, I *think*) in .NET-Core-SDK-style projects, you get transitive dependencies automatically. But that isn't the case when you just add a direct reference to a DLL.