# Can I use (string a, string b) Tuple Syntax with .NET 4.5.2?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-7.0

I am building an application in Visual Studio 2017 intended to be run on a Windows XP machine, but being able to use C# 7.0 tuple literals would be an ideal component to my solution.

I thought I could just add two nuget packages, `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` and `System.ValueType`, to enable my executable to use the syntax like `(string foo, string bar)` but I'm getting a syntax error, `CS8179  C# Predefined type is not defined or imported`.  Visual Studio's `ctrl + .` feature tries to get me to nuget-install `System.ValueType`, but it's already installed in the project.  Another option is `use local version 4.4.0`, but selecting that option doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: The answer is "yes", you can do this. Since apparently you can't there must be something else going wrong. Please explain further/include more details. I created a new C# class library project, set it to .NET 4.5.2, added a refence to the ValueTuple nuget package, then tried code similar to what you're asking about in the title and it works.

Comment: Fascinating, I just tried the same.  I was unable to get it to work.  I made a completely new project, installed specified nuget-packages, reverted to .NET 4.5.2, and added the function signature `public (string, int) GetTuple()`. Received the same compiler errors.  If you go to Project > Properties > Build > Advanced, what is your lang-version option set to? I am using C# Latest Major version (default)

Comment: Alright.  I guess the solution is that having `ctrl + .` take care of the installation of `System.ValueType` for you is what ultimately links it all up correctly.  However, if I install `System.ValueType` manually from nuget package manager then we have issues.  That's strange.

Comment: I never thought that uninstalling it and reinstalling it would do it.  Thanks, Lasse, you were a big help my friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382971/predefined-type-system-valuetuple%c2%b42%c2%b4-is-not-defined-or-imported)

Answer (score 3):

The solution to my issue was to uninstall the version of `System.ValueType` that I had installed manually and let the `ctrl + .` assistant take care of installing it.

Comment: I think you mean `ValueTuple`, not `ValueType`. Glad it worked out.