# how to initialize in C# like c++

Tags: c#, class, initialization

How do I init more than 1 variable in C#?

```
class file_list_output
{
   public file_list_output(ListView v, const int max) => veiw = v => max_ext_allowed = max;
}
```

cant quite figure it out

Comment: What is it you can't figure out?

Comment: how is this valid in c#    public file_list_output(ListView v) => veiw = v;

Comment: what you have is not valid, I placed an answer below which shows how to use an expression bodied constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

So your class has two properties:

```
public int Max_ext_allowed {get; private set;}
public ListView View {get; private set;}

//To do an expression bodied constructor
//The fat arrow => is replacing the typical { }
//And the next portion (View, Max_ext_allowed) is saying these are the properties being initialized
//Finally the last portion (v, max) is the set of values to set the properties to
public file_list_input(ListView v, int max) => (View, Max_ext_allowed) = (v, max);
```

Comment: thanks Ryan, not sure im a big fan of c# yet, time will tell

Comment: @joeblogs You're welcome. I updated this to explain it better with more comments. IF you are happy with my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: cheers for this,     public int max_ext_allowed { get; private set; }.   didnt no about that one

Comment: @joeblogs Yeah, its basically short hand for having a private variable with just a get method, the value can only be set at initialization.

Comment: where may this error be coming from.  System>ValueTuple2 is not defined or imported ------(v, max); is showing as the culprit

Comment: @joeblogs That last portion is using what is called a ValueTuple, you need to be using a newer version of .Net or import a package through Nuget, here is a post which explains how to do that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382971/predefined-type-system-valuetuple%C2%B42%C2%B4-is-not-defined-or-imported)

Comment: :) 4.6.1, windows all new to me. if i write a program and want it to run on win7, all i have to do is download 4.7.?? net version on host computer for it to work prior to running. is that correct

Comment: Depending on the version of .Net your application is targeting (or using), yes the target computer will need to have that version of .Net installed. With the new .Net Core, I believe alot of those issues should go away.

Comment: thanks, could you send me a link as how to format posts??

Comment: @joeblogs What do you mean? Like format your code on a StackOverflow post?

Comment: yup newbie ask. 4.7.1 solved the problem

Comment: @joeblogs Either place 4 whitespace characters before a line of text or you can highlight a portion of your text while writing in the box and use the {} icon button to do the indentation.

Comment: cheers,  thanks man.

Comment: @joeblogs Anytime. Happy coding! :P