# Can't return Value Tuple from C# Class Library to ASP.net Core 2.1 MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, portable-class-library, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I can't return Value Tuple from C# Class Library to ASP.net Core 2.1 MVC app, so I made a new solution to test only that point and it still did it.

Class Library (.net Framework 4.7):

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public (bool Success, string ReturnMessage) abc()
        {
            return (true, "hi");
        }
    }
}
```

.net Core 2.1 MVC Controller:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            var c = new Class1();
            var x = c.abc();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error in the MVC app at `c.abc()`:

```
Reference to type 'ValueTuple<,>' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found
```

If I create and return a Value Tuple within either project, it works.

I found this but it didn't help to install those Nuget packages (also why would that be required)?
[Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382971/predefined-type-system-valuetuple%C2%B42%C2%B4-is-not-defined-or-imported)

How can I successfully call this from the MVC app?

Comment: you can't call in core the framework library i think, but not sure

Comment: I can call a method in the Class Library fine from core, only the tuple fails.

Comment: .net core is recommended to be used with .net framework 4.7.1 and above, maybe try using 4.7.1 instead? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-targeting-net-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot call .Net Framework 4.7 class library from Asp.Net Core.

You can use .Net Standard, or ASP.Net Core for your Class Library.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question?!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Check my answer again.

Comment: I can call a method in the Class Library from the MVC app fine, it's only returning a Value Tuple that causes the issue (FYI it only took me like 2 minutes to setup an example solution to recreate the issue).

Comment: can you put it on github? so that I can check?

Comment: No time right now but really you can set it up yourself in like 2 mins. The only code I entered is in the question.

Comment: I am sorry I am little bit messy today. I found your problem. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked when I build the project with .Net framework 4.7 instead of older versions. it seems that this feature only works on .Net framework 4.7.
Thank You Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu your answer helped

Comment: Thanks, this should be a comment not an answer.