# unable to return multiple values ..System.ValueTuple related problem

Tags: c#, valuetuple

I'm self-learning using a book.. while working on methods the book introduces returning multiple values from a method. I've changed the code accordingly and installed related Microsoft NuGet package for tuples.. When I check the solution explorer, I can see that `System.ValueTuple` there and active.. But my project is not running accordingly as if I'd not installed the tuple package..

```
else if (division.IsChecked.HasValue && division.IsChecked.Value)
{
        int division, reminder;
        (division, reminder) = Divide(leftHandSide, rightHandSide);
                    result.Text = $" reminder ";
 }

....



        private (int, int) Divide(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide)
        {
            expression.Text = $" / ";
            int division = leftHandSide / rightHandSide;
            int reminder = leftHandSide % rightHandSide;
            return (division, reminder);
        }



        private void showResult(int answer) => result.Text = answer.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: "But my project is not running accordingly " Could you elaborate ? Does it throw an error ? or is something else?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting and which behavior is occuring?

Comment: Version of .NET Framework, Visual Studio, and C#?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS8179 Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported Methods E:\000_COGUT_visual\02_C# Kitap Kodları\02_Microsoft Press VS C# Step by Step\Chapter 3\Methods\Methods\MainPage.xaml.cs 84 Active

Comment: Sir Rufo this come on the line that I define the Divide method..

Comment: this is VS 2019..

Comment: Have you tried the old way with private Tuple<int, int> Divide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38382971/993547

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS8179 Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported Methods E:\000_COGUT_visual\02_C# Kitap Kodları\02_Microsoft Press VS C# Step by Step\Chapter 3\Methods\Methods\MainPage.xaml.cs 89 Active
This is the second error comes with line 89 which is "return (division, reminder);"

Comment: Can you please provied a [mre]